# Rsync copy files that I don't have already using a list

Tags: rsync, copy

I have two separate computers with the same MEDIA folder which is quite large. These folders have the same structure but in one computer there are more files.

What I would like to do is something like this:

1) Scan folder on computer A, create list of files I already have.

2) Copy list to a computer B and run "copy files that are not in the list" to my external drive.

Is it possible to do this with rsync?

Thank you so much, this would be really a powerful hack.

Comment: Are those two computers connected to the same network? If not, is it possible to connect them? Or the only option to "sync" them is via an external drive?

Comment: No, they are not connected. That's why I would like to make a list of files I already have and to copy the rest of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sync a directory from one computer to another using an external drive, without copying the whole directory:

- In the destination (computer A, in your case):

  Generate the list of files you already have and save it to the external drive:

  ```
  cd /PATH/TO/MEDIA
  find -type f | cut -c2- > /PATH/TO/EXTERNAL/DRIVE/my_files
  ```

  You have to `cd` to the folder you want to sync, so `find` will generate a list of files using relative paths.
- In the origin (computer B, in your case):

  Copy only the files you don't have to the external drive:

  ```
  rsync -a --exclude-from=/PATH/TO/my_files /PATH/TO/MEDIA /PATH/TO/EXTERNAL/DRIVE
  ```

  Make sure you **don't** include a trailing slash (`/`) in `/PATH/TO/MEDIA`.
- Back to destination (computer A, in your case):

  Copy the files from the external drive to your directory:

  ```
  rsync -a /PATH/TO/EXTERNAL/DRIVE/MEDIA/ /PATH/TO/MEDIA
  ```

  Now, make sure you **do** include a trailing slash in `/PATH/TO/EXTERNAL/DRIVE/MEDIA/`.

More info: [Rsync manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/rsync.1.html).